# How to Display DIV OnTop of Canvas Background

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, canvas

I have nice Beautiful Stars Canvas Background script, and i wonder- how do i Display a DIV ontop of that Canvas script.

I try to put the DIV in or under the canvas tags (you can see the results on the link below) but it display nothing, or bring it at the bottom of the page in a way that you have no way to see it .

Here is my code:

**HTML**:

```
<canvas></canvas>
<div style="background-color:red">this is a test</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
  background: black
}
```

**JS**:

```
var n_stars = 150
var colors = [ '#176ab6', '#fb9b39']
for ( let i = 0; i < 98; i++) {
  colors.push( '#fff')
}

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

addEventListener( 'resize', () => {
  canvas.width = innerWidth
  canvas.height = innerHeight
  stars = []
  init()
})

canvas.style.background = '#000'
var c = canvas.getContext('2d')

const randomInt = ( max, min) => Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min) + min)

var bg = c.createRadialGradient( canvas.width/ 2, canvas.height * 3, canvas.height ,canvas.width/ 2,canvas.height , canvas.height * 4);
bg.addColorStop(0,"#32465E");
bg.addColorStop(.4,"#000814");
bg.addColorStop(.8,"#000814");
bg.addColorStop(1,"#000");

class Star {
  constructor( x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x || randomInt( 0, canvas.width)
    this.y = y || randomInt( 0, canvas.height)
    this.radius = radius || Math.random() * 1.1
    this.color = color || colors[randomInt(0, colors.length)]
    this.dy = -Math.random() * .3
  }
  draw () {
    c.beginPath()
    c.arc( this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI *2 )
    c.shadowBlur = randomInt( 3, 15)
    c.shadowColor = this.color
    c.strokeStyle = this.color
    c.fillStyle = 'rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5)'
    c.fill()
    c.stroke()
    c.closePath()
  }
  update( arrayStars = [] ) {
    if ( this.y - this.radius < 0 ) this.createNewStar( arrayStars )

    this.y += this.dy
    this.draw()
  }
  createNewStar( arrayStars = [] ) {
    let i = arrayStars.indexOf( this )
    arrayStars.splice( i, 1)
    arrayStars.push( new Star( false, canvas.height + 5))
  }
}
var stars = []
function init() {
  for( let i = 0; i < n_stars; i++ ) {
    stars.push( new Star( ) )
  }
}
init()

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate)
  c.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  c.fillStyle = bg
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  stars.forEach( s => s.update( stars ))
}
animate()
```

Here is a live one: [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/rami7377/pen/PVoxLo)

Comment: Positioning....see "how to overlay"

Comment: You might use postion absolute for the div https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZLdMO and there is a typo in `style="backgrond-color:red"`

Comment: Can you put it as an answer so i can choose?

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this (used a wrapper element and positioned div absolutely on top of canvas element):

```js
var n_stars = 150
var colors = [ '#176ab6', '#fb9b39']
for ( let i = 0; i < 98; i++) {
  colors.push( '#fff')
}

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
canvas.width = innerWidth
canvas.height = innerHeight

addEventListener( 'resize', () => {
  canvas.width = innerWidth
  canvas.height = innerHeight
  stars = []
  init()
})

canvas.style.background = '#000'
var c = canvas.getContext('2d')

const randomInt = ( max, min) => Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min) + min)

var bg = c.createRadialGradient( canvas.width/ 2, canvas.height * 3, canvas.height ,canvas.width/ 2,canvas.height , canvas.height * 4);
bg.addColorStop(0,"#32465E");
bg.addColorStop(.4,"#000814");
bg.addColorStop(.8,"#000814");
bg.addColorStop(1,"#000");

class Star {
  constructor( x, y, radius, color) {
    this.x = x || randomInt( 0, canvas.width)
    this.y = y || randomInt( 0, canvas.height)
    this.radius = radius || Math.random() * 1.1
    this.color = color || colors[randomInt(0, colors.length)]
    this.dy = -Math.random() * .3
  }
  draw () {
    c.beginPath()
    c.arc( this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI *2 )
    c.shadowBlur = randomInt( 3, 15)
    c.shadowColor = this.color
    c.strokeStyle = this.color
    c.fillStyle = 'rgba( 255, 255, 255, .5)'
    c.fill()
    c.stroke()
    c.closePath()
  }
  update( arrayStars = [] ) {
    if ( this.y - this.radius < 0 ) this.createNewStar( arrayStars )

    this.y += this.dy
    this.draw()
  }
  createNewStar( arrayStars = [] ) {
    let i = arrayStars.indexOf( this )
    arrayStars.splice( i, 1)
    arrayStars.push( new Star( false, canvas.height + 5))
  }
}
var stars = []
function init() {
  for( let i = 0; i < n_stars; i++ ) {
    stars.push( new Star( ) )
  }
}
init()

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame( animate)
  c.clearRect( 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  c.fillStyle = bg
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  stars.forEach( s => s.update( stars ))
}
animate()
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden; 
  background: black
}
.wrapper{
position: relative;
display: block;
}
.wrapper > canvas {
position: relative;
display: block;
}
.wrapper > div {
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<canvas></canvas>
<div style="background-color:red">this is a test</div>
</div>
```